# Why did the Others put Karl in the chair in Room 23?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost

I just found out that there is an epilogue episode to Lost, named [The New Man in Charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Man_in_Charge), that answers some of the questions left open by the finale, for example

- where the Dharma Initiative packages dropped from the sky come from,
- why there are polar bears on the island,
- what happened to Walt and
- what the purpose of Room 23 was.

The full epilogue can be seen on Youtube:

Apparently Room 23 was used by Dharma to question the captured indigenous population about Jacob and then cause partial amnesia to make them forget about it, so Dharma would not risk a war by violating their truce.

The first time we see Room 23, Alex' friend Karl is being tortured there. ("Not in Portland", 3x07)

[image: Karl in Room 23]
([Image source](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Not_in_Portland?file=3X07_KarlRoom23.jpg))

In retrospect of this new information about the purpose of Room 23, is there any indication what the Others were hoping to achieve by brainwashing Karl? Why are they trying to erase his memory?

Comment: I don't think it's so much the others trying to erase his memory, as it is Ben trying to keep Karl away from Alex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was stated in the season 3 finale, "Through the Looking Glass":

> ALEX: You locked Karl in a cage. You put him in a room and tried to brainwash him.
>
> BEN: I didn't want him to get you pregnant. I suppose I overreacted. We better get going.

[Transcript from Lostpedia](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass_transcript)

It's worth noting that a big plot line in season 3 is that pregnant women die on the island.